# Cannot create file mapping for a file I just opened, get "path not found"

Tags: c, winapi, file-manipulation

I'm trying to the `CreateFileMapping()` function (on windows).

Now, in this piece of code:

```
hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); 
hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeInBlocks*SO_BLOCK_SIZE, filename);
```

The file is created allright, but the value of `hFileMapping` is `NULL`! Which is weird because I'm using `hFile` (which is a valid handle!) and when I check `GetLastError()` status after the call to `CreateFileMApping()` I'm getting `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, which is weird, because another function just used it to create the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is from that functions?

Comment: Yeap, when I'm checking it before that call I'm getting what's set there by `CreateFile()` - ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (which is ok, it overwrites it and sets the error code to that)

Comment: The value of GetLastError() is meaningless if the function call succeeds.

Comment: Forgot to mention, `hFileMapping` is NULL. Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, been doing some digging (should've been beforehand, I know). The last parameter of `CreateFileMapping()` should be a string NOT containing backslashes. And I've used the filepath I've created as that parameter (to make it a unique name). So, the error returned was actually applying to that parameter and NOT to the file handle passed as the first parameter.

Comment: The last parameter is the name of the file mapping, not the name of the file. You probably don't need to name your file mapping, so just pass NULL.

Comment: The mapping was supposed to be used by multiple processes, and a `OpenFileMapping()` can actually open a mapping by using the name parameter. I thought the path would be a good unique key. Apparently not :)

Comment: You should decorate the name with something specific to your application. Otherwise, your name may collide with another application which decides to name file mappings after file names...

Comment: Makes sense. Need to think of a naming convention in any case. Thanks